# og:image content is recognized as a valid URL but is unable to retrieve image

Tags: caching, facebook-opengraph

We recently moved servers and I've been having this problem since.

I tried parsing this [url1](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.riotengine.in%2F2012%2F05%2F12%2Fyou-and-i-owe-this-man-carroll-shelby%2F) in the Facebook Debug tool, and the thumbnail retrieved using the content of the og:image tag is displayed fine, but it won't display when I 'like' the story and it appears in my profile . This was a story posted before switching servers.

Now when I try parsing this [url2](http://www.riotengine.in/2012/05/19/porsche-918-spyder-is-on-the-road/) in the Facebook Debug tool, the thumbnail is not retrieved and with previous case the thumbnail won't display in my profile when I like this story. This is a story posted after switching servers.

The funny thing I try repeating these actions and the thumbnail does pop up randomly.

How does Facebook retrieve the image from my server? Does the problem have something to do with how this is done?

Comment: UPDATE: The problem has been solved without my intervention. I would guess that it had to do with the DNS propagation, as soon as it was completed, the thumbnails were being shown properly. Thanks for your time people.

Answer (score 0):

At one point, I thought FB would not show a thumbnail on a second post. Or something. It seemed to show the thumbnail again, if I changed the URL a bit (put some fake parameters in the url). 
YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Remove every `og` meta tags from the page, debug it into the facebook debugger tool, when it shows nothing, put the correct `og` meta tags again and debug again with facebok debugger tool.

This is a weird problem with facebook. It caches the old incorrect values sometimes.

Comment: That's the thing! There haven't been any incorrect values. They're  good. It's just that FB seems to be incapable of getting the image.. why would that be?

Comment: Try with incorrect different image url. Debug it, put the correct one, debug it again. Weird way for even weirder facebook. Believe me, it works :)